# Fill only one previous NaN column value with following value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let us assume I have the following dataframe df:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, None], [4, None, None], [None, 1, 9]])
df
    0   1   2
0   1   2   Nan
1   4   NaN NaN
2 NaN   1   9
```

How can I fill the column2 the row 1 with the following value of the next row (in this case row 2), and leave the otherone in row 0 empty. So that only the first previous NaN gets filled (for column2), that it generates the output:

```
    0   1   2
0   1   2   Nan
1   4   NaN 9
2 NaN   1   9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `bfill` with a `limit`:

```
df[2] = df[2].bfill(limit=1)

>>> df
     0    1    2
0  1.0  2.0  NaN
1  4.0  NaN  9.0
2  NaN  1.0  9.0
```

Answer (score 0):

This code checks for all columns & where ever there are consecutive `NaN`, fill the last `NaN` with next value in that column.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, None], [4, None, None], [None, 1, 9]])

def fill_consecutive_nans(series):
    # Identify blocks of NaNs
    mask = series.isna()
    
    # For every NaN, if the following one is also NaN, replace it with the previous valid value
    return np.where(mask & mask.shift(1, fill_value=False), series.bfill(), series)

# Apply the function to each column in the dataframe
df = df.apply(fill_consecutive_nans)

print(df)

 0    1    2
0  1.0  2.0  NaN
1  4.0  NaN  9.0
2  NaN  1.0  9.0
```